# Using Erase tool for replacement ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, erase

I have two layers (polygon type) and i want to erase the red polygon from the pale blue polygon, so i will get another polygon just without the red polygon feature. 
I'm work with desktop license, so i can't use the "Erase" tool. I need ArcGIS solution. (I can do it in QGIS).

[image]

Comment: PolyGeo, i edit my question

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on the workflow that you are asking about, please?  The Erase tool is about polygon-on-polygon overlay, and so your addition of an RGB requirement seems out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Union` tool to put the two inputs together. Then start an editing session and delete the part of the polygon you don't need. Note that `Union` will only work with up to two input features without an advanced license.